# What are some good tools for performance analysis with asp.net apps?

Tags: asp.net, performance

Are there some good tools that can analyze the performance issues in an asp.net application?  i google and found a couple like dotTrace, stimulustechnology. have anyone used a better one?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=unmet_need&utm_campaign=antsperformanceprofiler&gclid=CN-OxO_1oKACFRLxDAodPDcCbA) is pretty good, and you can download a free trial. Also, a handy built in feature of .Net that should be able to help with performance analysis in case you don't know is using tracing. [Here](http://www.asp101.com/articles/robert/tracing/default.asp) is a link that will help you get started using tracing.

Answer (score 2):

[ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/features.htm) is probably a good choice other than what you have listed. Please note that it is not free

Answer (score 0):

.NET CLR Profiler is a good one.

WinDBG is pretty good too.